# start up script virtual machine in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can see in one of the GCE Instance start up script as

```
userdel -r userid
```

due to this user is not able to SSH through browser.

My question is which logs  how do we find who has added this startup script to the vm and when?

can we use some logs?

Comment: I think this is the documentation you may be looking for ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging

I think it is the "Admin Activity Audit Logs" you specifically want.   It is also likely that the operation you will be looking for will be "compute.instances.setMetadata".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If any of the answers below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can check logs for this in activity log.

you can use below url by replacing your project id.

https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know who adds a startup script to the VM, you can check the *Admin Activity audit logs and the System Event audit logs*.
Admin Activity audit logs contain log entries for API calls or other actions that modify the configuration or metadata of resources.
And, System Event audit logs contain log entries for Google Cloud actions that modify the configuration of resources.

> Google Cloud services write audit logs that record administrative
> activities and accesses within your Google Cloud resources. Audit logs
> help you answer "who did what, where, and when?" within your Google
> Cloud resources with the same level of transparency as in on-premises
> environments.  Cloud Audit Logs provides the following audit logs for
> each Cloud project, folder, and organization:
>
> - Admin Activity audit logs
> - Data Access audit logs
> - System Event audit logs
> - Policy Denied audit logs

*The Data Access audit logs* can be very useful too, but are disabled by default, Data Access audit logs contain API calls that read the configuration or metadata of resources, as well as user-driven API calls that create, modify, or read user-provided resource data. If you want to enable it, please follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access).

**To view the Audits logs**

> 1. In the Cloud console, go to the Logging> Logs Explorer page.
> 2. Select an existing Cloud project, folder, or organization.
> 3. In the Query builder pane, do the following:
> 4. In Resource type, select the Google Cloud resource whose audit logs
>    you want to see.
>
> In Log name, select the audit log type that you want to see:
>
> - For Admin Activity audit logs, select activity.
> - For Data Access audit logs, select data_access.
> - For System Event audit logs, select system_event.
> - For Policy Denied audit logs, select policy.
>
> If you don't see these options, then there aren't any audit logs of
> that type available in the Cloud project, folder, or organization.

If you want to know more about Audit logs in GCP, please follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit).